# Perl program not getting executed in xampp

Tags: perl

I am very new to CGI programming in Perl.

In order to learn it i installed xampp 2 days back.
But I am unable to execute my perl code . The code goes as folows:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use CGI;
$co = new CGI;
print $co->header,
$co->start_html(title=>'CGI Example'),
$co->center($co->hi('Subhayan welcome to CGI')),
$co->end_html;
```

Have saved the code in a text file named : Subhayan1.cgi and kept it in the folder cgi-bin under xampp folder in C drive.

When i try to execute this through my web browser typing :
"http://localhost/cgi-bin/Subhayan1.cgi" it comes up with a "Object not found page".

I checked the apache configuration file under : xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf.

I checked the entry : ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "C:/xampp/cgi-bin/"

It looks like pointing to the correct directory.

What is the issue here can anyone help please???

Comment: Did you make sure that your script is executable?
chmod +x Subhayan1.cgi

Comment: @ddoxey - does Windows use chmod?  I thought it didn't.

Comment: Yes, you're right windows doesn't have chmod. But I'm pretty sure there's some equivalent. Probably right-click and selecting an executable checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

You should the webserver access/error log to see what is the real error.

Are you able to run the cgi script from windows commandline?

For Perl CGI script you should install Perl and CGI.pm.

```
cmd> C:/xampp/cgi-bin/Subhayan1.cgi

The output should be:

Http 1.1
<doctype...
```

If everything works fine this point you should be sure that your installed Perl version added as handler for CGI scripts in Apache.

Details:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560749/how-do-i-configure-apache2-to-run-perl-cgi-scripts

http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-install-apache2-webserver-with-phpcgi-and-perl-support-in-ubuntu-server.html

Answer (score 0):

Try the below codes..it will works fine.

```
#!"C:\xampp\perl\bin\perl.exe"
use CGI;
$co = new CGI;
print $co->header,
$co->start_html('CGI Example'),
$co->center('welcome to CGI'),
$co->end_html;
```

(or)

```
#!"C:\xampp\perl\bin\perl.exe"
use CGI;
$co = new CGI;
print $co->header;

print "
<html>
<title>CGI Example</title>
<head></head>
<body>
 welcome to CGI
</body>
</html>
";
```

Comment: Hello! Welcome to Super User! Mind explaining *why*, this works, not just how?